# phrasal verb get something into

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

> Association Football (soccer) is played by two teams, each of 11 players, who attempt to get the ball into the opponent's goal, usually by kicking it.

What does "to get the ball into the opponent's goal" mean ?

Comment: It means kicking the ball past the goal line, therefore scoring a goal. I'm not quite sure what you don't understand, please elaborate.

Comment: This is tricky, because I think this is actually **not** the phrasal verb it looks like.  I assume you understand the word "into" and that is not the problem.  "Get" has many definitions, and I think the appropriate one is [**5 b: to cause to move**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get).  They could kick the ball into the goal, or carry it into the goal, or whatever, but **get** covers any possible way of doing it.

Comment: Note the *difference* between [the phrasal verb](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/get-into) and your example.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate your help. Now I understand what it means

Comment: You're welcome!  I am going to promote my comment into an answer, so if you feel that it was helpful, you can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricky sentence to understand, because I think this "get X into Y" is actually not [the phrasal verb it looks like (which would be *to get into* something)](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/get-into).

"Get" has many definitions, and I think [the appropriate definition of "get" here is](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get)

> 5 b: to cause to move.

"Into" just means "towards the inside of something"; the ball is going *into* the goal because it is moving to the inside of the goal from the outside.

So the players are *causing* the ball to move into the goal.  They could kick the ball into the goal, or carry it into the goal, or whatever, but *get* covers any possible way of doing it.

Comment: *Get* can be used like *put* if the object is far away and might require a third party or a major effort to obtain, i.e. you are expected to *cause* it to be somewhere more than actually move it yourself.